# How to find users' location during a web site visit in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
 echo Html::a( Yii::t( 'app', ' {modelClass}', [
                    'modelClass' => $loc_name,
                    ] ), [ 'site/city' ], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-link  fa fa-map-marker btn-primary city' ]
                    );
```

given above is a code for a dropdown to select a city. is there any way to get 
it automatically by sensing the location of the user in yii2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the Url helper class.

```
use yii\helpers\Url

// Current URL route...
Url::current()
```

It has a current() method that returns the current URL. You can see more about it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html)

Comment: i wan't my application to identify the current location of the user.

Comment: How is the current url not the current location of the user?

Comment: my mistake i didn't think about that.

Comment: Haha, no worries mate, does this sort the problem for you then?

Comment: Lol, nope, UK born and bred, I do a mean Aussie accent though ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use geoip. There's a module for Yii2:
https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-geoip